# position the translation of the English sentence on the right edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an English sentence and its translation to an RTL sentence right below it:

```html
<div class="sample-sentence">
   <p class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
   <p class="rtl">برات آماده کنم</p>
</div>
```

So far I can position the RTL sentence only at the very left or center of the English one.

How can I position RTL sentence at the right edge of the English sentence like this:

[image]

Comment: Make the div container inline-block, so that it takes its width from the wider of the two child elements, and then work with text-align on the paragraphs …?

Comment: before answering, what is your css file look like? I would like to see what's in there before diagnosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` and `justify-content` might help:

```css
.sample-sentence {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
}

/* snippet demo purpose */
body>p {text-align:center;background:none;}
p {margin:0;background:#bee}
```

```html
<div class="sample-sentence">
  <p class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
  <p dir="rtl">برات آماده کنم</p>
</div>
<hr>
<p>no matter the initial direction of the doc</p>
<hr>
<div dir="rtl" >
<div class="sample-sentence">
  <p>برات آماده کنم</p>
  <p dir="ltr" class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left: auto` on the target element used with `display: flex` and `justify-content: flex-end` is one way.

`inline-block` is also used so the width of the parent element resizes to it's content.

```css
div, p {
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.rtl {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-sentence">
   <p class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
   <p class="rtl">برات آماده کنم</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave three options for placing the bottom text on the right. But in fact, there are many options for solving this problem :)

1. Solution with `text-align: right` for `.sample-sentence`:

```css
.sample-sentence {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-sentence">
   <p class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
   <p class="rtl">برات آماده کنم</p>
</div>
```

2. Solution with `width: fit-content` for `.sample-sentence`, and pseudo-class `:nth-child` for second `p` tag:

```css
.sample-sentence {
    width: fit-content;
}

.sample-sentence p:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-sentence">
   <p class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
   <p class="rtl">برات آماده کنم</p>
</div>
```

3. Solution with `flex`:

```css
.sample-sentence {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sample-sentence p:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-sentence">
   <p class="eng">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
   <p class="rtl">برات آماده کنم</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float="right"` to your RTL class. This will bring content with RTL to the right of the screen. If your div size is fixed, it will start from extreme right of the `<div>`